# Encrypting a AES key using RSA Key

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa

I have written a code to encrypt a aes key and decrypt it but it dosent seem to be happening.Why is this so?

```
KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
keyGen.initialize(2048);
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey pubKey= pair.getPublic();
PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
Cipher c1 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
KeyGenerator aesKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
aesKeyGenerator.init(256);               
 Key aesKey = rijndaelKeyGenerator.generateKey();                
Cipher symmetricCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
byte[] encodedKeyBytes = c1.doFinal(aeslKey.getEncoded());
SecretKey aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKeyBytes, "aes1");
Cipher dec = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
dec.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
symmetricCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey1, spec);                   
if(aesKey.getEncoded() == dec.doFinal(c1.doFinal(aesKey.getEncoded())) )
{                            
    // Not reaching here but is supposed to 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the line:

```
SecretKey aesKey1 = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKeyBytes, "aes1");
```

You are converting the still (RSA) encrypted `aesKey` to a `SecretKey`. At that spot you should have decrypted the key first. `"aes1"` is not any known type of key either.

Please try and separate the various wrapping (key encryption) and encryption statements into methods, and make separate methods for the unwrapping and decryption. Just throwing statements around is not going to get you anywhere. Try to make a *methodical* attempt to solve the problem at hand.